# Usining Forge minecraft on windows 8.1 non-admin accounts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge, windows-8

Since moving onto windows 8.1 I've set up user accounts for my kids- This means I can have separate safety settings on the browsers etc. When installing most apps it's just a case I install on one account (usually mine - the admin account) and it shows up in all the sub-accounts. This is probably because minecraft doesn't install to the programs/ folder.Now I can make a shortcut to the mincraft launcher from the sub accounts and run minecraft that way but Forge isn't present.
 I have installed forge on my admin account and it works fine but if I try install forge while in a sub account it doesn't work. 
Has anyone come across this and has a solution or does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup and to work around the problem I did the following:

- Install Minecraft in your child's account.
- Run the Forge installer, it should ask for the username/password of an administrator
- Enter your username/password to allow the Forge installer to start. Forge should now show the directory it is going to install in to. This will default to the administrator's Minecraft folder and not the child's Minecraft folder.
- Change the folder where Forge is going to install to to be the Minecraft folder of your child's Window's account.
- Let the installation complete as normal.

Now when Minecraft is started on the child's account, Forge should be available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either install forge for each account or try to setup a symbolic link on the .minecraft/versions folder.  I have never created a symbolic link in Windows, so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Most users on windows 8 use the newer version of Java. That newer version is not supported with some versions of Minecraft Forge or Forge ModLoader.

Comment: Heeey, if you could just go ahead and write down what's being told in the video.. That'd be great.